# PromQl: Calculating p99 over a time interval

Tags: prometheus, promql

I’ve got multiple time series latency metrics and one for each kubernetes pod. I need to calculate the p99 latency metric for the entire service ,i.e, all the pods combined, over every 5min interval. How do I do that?

Here’s the sample time series data:

```
service_latency(app=“payments”,pod_name=“pod1”)
service_latency(app=“payments”,pod_name=“pod2”)
service_latency(app=“payments”,pod_name=“pod3”)
```

---

PromQl that I have so far:

`quantile_over_time(0.99, service_latency{app=“payments”}[5m])`

---

However, the above PromQL returns p99 metric for each pod rather than for the entire service. I also am not sure if it is indeed calculating the p99 for every 5 minutes like I intended it to.

Can a PromQL expert here please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you store in Prometheus the latency of every request as a separate sample with `service_latency` name, then Prometheus doesn't provide the ability to calculate percentile over all the samples received from multiple pods (aka multiple time series) over the given lookbehind window.

I'd suggest switching to [Prometheus histograms](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#histogram) instead. Histogram buckets can be aggregated over multiple time series, so you can estimate the needed percentile over multiple pods over the given lookbehind window using the following query:

```
histogram_quantile(
  0.99,
    sum(increase(
    service_latency_seconds_bucket[5m]
    )) by (le)
)
```

See [histogram_quantile docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#histogram_quantile).

Histograms also usually require less disk space and less cpu during querying comparing to the case when storing a separate sample per each incoming request into Prometheus. This is especially visible on highly loaded service serving thousands requests per second.

P.S. if you still decide to stick with the current schema (e.g. storing in the tsdb a separate sample per each incoming request), then you can try VictoriaMetrics - this is a Prometheus-like monitoring system I work on. It provides the [histogram_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#histogram_over_time) function, which calculates a histogram over raw samples on the given time range. Later the returned histograms can be aggregated over multiple time series, and the `histogarm_quantile` funtion can be applied to them. For example, the following query estimates 99th percentile over all the raw samples of `service_latency{app="payments"}` time series over the last 5 minutes:

```
histogram_quantile(0.99,
  sum(histogram_over_time(
    service_latency{app="payments"}[5m]
  )) by (vmrange)
)
```

See also https://valyala.medium.com/improving-histogram-usability-for-prometheus-and-grafana-bc7e5df0e350

Answer (score 0):

You must define how you define the "metric of the entire service". Because you have 3 `service_latency` metrics for each application instance which have the same value. What if 1 instance gives a value of 100 ms, and the others give 10 ms? You have to define this manually in a formula.

- Let's assume you want to track the average of all these metrics, then use:

```
quantile_over_time(0.99, (avg(service_latency{app=“payments”})[5m])
```

So we get a 0.99 percentile of the average values for the last 5 minutes.

- Or if you want to track only the maximum delay across all services:

```
quantile_over_time(0.99, (max(service_latency{app=“payments”})[5m])
```

- You can also make a more universal query for Grafana, which will display a graph for each service:

```
quantile_over_time(0.99, (avg by (app) (service_latency)[5m])
```

For clarity, here is a graph where the two queries are compared:

```
# green query:
sum(irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode!='idle',instance="$node"}))

# yellow query:
quantile_over_time(1, (avg(sum(irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode!="idle", instance="$node"}))))[10m])
```

[image]